# How to run .bat file using spring boot batch process

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, batch-processing

I have a batch file which is running through windows task scheduler and it will he execute the jar file every 10 hours repeately.

Now, I'm trying to run the same batch file using spring boot batch process as a task scheduler. but i didn't get solution for this.

How can i resolve the this issue?

Comment: Do you want to do batching or scheduling? It sounds like you want to do scheduling, so Spring Batch won't help you there.

Comment: I have a Java Runnable jar file and i'm trying to execute the jar using spring boot process. Earlier, i have used to execute the jar with help of .bat & windows scheduler.

Answer (score 1):

In your schedule method, try like this:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("file.bat");
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/

Spring Boot scheduler can schedule your tasks and accepts CRON like expression to scheduling recurring tasks.

You can use Java [ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) API to trigger your batch (.bat) file

Answer (score 0):

You can implement simple [Spring scheduling tasks](https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/) as following

```
@Component
public class RunCommandScheduledTask {

    private final ProcessBuilder builder;
    private final Logger logger; //  Slf4j in this example
    // inject location/path of the bat file 
    @Inject
    public RunCommandScheduledTask(@Value("${bat.file.path.property}") String pathToBatFile) {
        this.builder = new ProcessBuilder(pathToBatFile);
        this.logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("RunCommandScheduledTask");
    }
    // cron to execute each 10h 
    @Scheduled(cron = "0 */10 * * *")
    public void runExternalCommand() {
        try {
            final Process process = builder.start();
            if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                // pipe command output and proxy it into log
                try (BufferedReader out = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1))) {
                    String str = null;
                    for (;;) {
                        str = out.readLine();
                        if (null == str)
                            break;
                        logger.debug(str);
                    }
                }
            }
            process.waitFor();
        } catch (IOException exc) {
            logger.error("Can not execute external command", exc);
        } catch (InterruptedException exc) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }

}

.....
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class);
    }
}
```